# Having trouble with compiling this code

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I'm working on a very simple GLFW project. I find that I need both `<GL/glfw.h>` and `<GL/glfw3.h>` headers to be able to use certain things. When I include both of these headers together, I'm getting an error:

> error: conflicting declaration `'typedef void (*GLFWwindowsizefun)(GLFWwindow*, int, int)'`

And it points to the `glfw3.h` source code where there is that exact `typedef` as above.

Has anyone ever experienced this? How would I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think you need both `glfw.h` and `glfw3.h`? You certainly don't. Those headers are for different versions of the `glfw` library. Use the header for the library version you want to use (and the one you link).

Comment: When I remove `#include <GL/glfw3.h>` it gives me the error `GLFW_SAMPLES was not declared in this scope` because I'm using `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);` in my code. Also, when I only remove `#include <GL/glfw.h>` it gives me the error `undefined reference to glfwWindowHint`. So I think I need both headers for the program to work.

Comment: The first error, the undeclared identifier, is a _compiler_ warning. The second one, the undefined reference, is a _linker_ error. These errors prove that the code indeed is written against GLFW3, but you are trying to link it with an older version of the library.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for how to fix it?

Comment: Typically,the glfw3 library is called `libglfw3.so`/`.a` (on linux) or `glfw32.lib` (on windows/MSVC). So link that libarary, not just `glfw`.

Comment: Sorry I'm really new to this and I'm not sure how to link libraries. I've only been following tutorials I could find. Where exactly can I find `glfw32.lib` and what do I do with it?

Comment: What platform are you using? And what compiler/toolchain? You somehow have to specify what libraries you have to link. If you use some IDE (like VisualStudio, QTCreator, Eclipse, whatever), there is a dialog for that.

Comment: On on Windows using CodeBlocks with g++.

Comment: OK, I have _no_ experience with CodeBlocks. But there must be some linker settings for your project. Can't help you there. But google might.

Comment: There is a linker setting, [I see it](http://i.gyazo.com/dabba9e91b50fe13b2fd5d35046bfc2e.png). But then how do I find `glfw32.lib`?

Comment: Well, you either download the precompiled libraries for your platform, or you compile them for yourself. Use the [glfw download page](http://www.glfw.org/download.html) the necessary files. Also have a look at [this GLFW guide](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build.html).